# Usar UPDATE para actualizar una columna en una tabla desde otra tabla con la misma columna

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Estoy intentando actualizar una columna especifica de una tabla por medio de otra; las dos tienen valores, pero quiero sobreescribir todos los campos (con el mismo id en las dos tab's sin sobreescribir los que no los tengan) de la columna en la *tab A* por los datos de la columna en la *tab B*.
He intentado con este código

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1
FROM
    MiTab1 AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN MiTab2 AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.id = Table_B.id
WHERE
    Table_B.col3 = 1
```

pero me genera el siguiente error:

> Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'FROM ...

Comment: EN qué motor de base de datos? Procura indicarlo en las etiqutas de la pregunta (o en cualquier lugar de la pregunta) :) Por ahora, los UPDATE siempre serán UPDATE SET WHERE y ya la magia adicional depende del motor

Comment: Ok listo, y es phpmyadmin

Comment: PHPMyAdmin no es el motor de base de datos, es nada más una herramienta, lo mismo va para XAMPP... ¿Es MySQL, MariaDB?

Comment: MySQL  es el motor de base de datos

Comment: @Alfabravo, ¿Consideras que para esta publicación, el hecho de que sea MariaDB y MSQL vendrían a compartir la misma respuesta? Pregunto porque no veo una diferencia palpable entre estos dos motores para este problema. Igual para añadirle la etiqueta y que sea más fácil de encontrar

Comment: @Cuauhtli considero que para esta publicación, estás respondiéndole al que no es :P En mi opinión profesional, es momento para el páaaaanico (y ya en serio, estoy de acuerdo en que no hay diferencia entre esos dos para este caso)

Comment: @Alfabravo, jaja, claro. Sólo lo decía para mejorar el etiquetado de la publicación para que los que lean la pregunta, y la probable respuesta, vean que se puede adaptar a su caso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
update TablaA a, tablaB b
set a.campo = b.campo
where a.campo = b.campo and b.col3 = 1
```

Aquí se hace un **Update** interrelacionando dos tablas por un campo en común y actualizando el campo de **TablaA** con el respectivo campo de **TablaB**. Se tiene en cuenta además la condición que pones en tu consulta de **b.col3 = 1**.

Comment: Muchas gracias...

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la sintaxis de tabla múltiple (multiple-table sintax) según lo que dice el manual de MySql versión 8 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html aunque en este sitio me parece más claro https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/

```
UPDATE T1, T2,
    [INNER JOIN | LEFT JOIN] T1 ON T1.C1 = T2. C1
SET T1.C2 = T2.C2, 
    T2.C3 = expr
WHERE condition
```

Este es un ejemplo que lo probé en mi xampp(xampp-win32-5.6.40-0-VC11) que corre mariadb 10.1.37

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE table1(id INT, valor VARCHAR (20));
DROP TABLE IF exists table2;
CREATE TABLE table2(id INT, valor VARCHAR (10));

INSERT INTO table1(id, valor)
VALUES
    (1, 'primero'),
    (2, 'segundo'),
    (3, 'tercero');
    
INSERT INTO table2(id, valor)
VALUES
    (1, 'cuarto'),
    (2, 'quinto'),
    (3, 'sexto');        
    
SELECT * from table1;    

UPDATE table1 AS t1 
    INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 
        on t1.id = t2.id
SET
    t1.valor = concat(t1.valor, ' ', t2.valor)
WHERE
    t1.id > 1;
    
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Las tablas a actualizar deben colocarse luego del la palabra UPDATE y puedes hacer inner join, left join, etc.

Espero que te ayude.